# Mac Book won't install software

Tags: install, memory, software

I just recently replaced the drive in my MacBook Pro and after partitioning the drive, formatting it correctly, and multiple attempts to install it  the process won't complete.

When going through the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> menu, OS Mountain Lion start to download  but when it's almost finished an error appear in the install log that says `"Failed to verify InstallESD.dmg: hdiutil verify failed"` and the download strat all over again.

If I go through the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> menu, OS Catilina start to download and when it's almost finished an error appear that says `"an error occurred when installing macOS Catalina"`.

I've read that both of these problems might be related to RAM so I took both out and reinstalled them as somebody suggested and still no luck. I really just want to make sure that it's the RAM before I go and spend any money. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: How is it formatted, precisely? Mountain Lion will want GUID/HFS+ & Catalina will want GUID/APFS. Catalina will be able to see HFS but not install to it, Mountain Lion can't see APFS. Neither will work if the underlying scheme is MBR instead of GUID.

Comment: The digital signatures in old OS X installers have long expired, so they won't pass the verification. Try to set your system clock back, near the release date of your system. For Mountain Lion, try 2013/01/01.

Comment: The digital signature issue was resolved a year ago. Any recently downloaded installer does not need the date hack.

Comment: @Tetsujin I believe I formatted it differently for both Mountain Lion and Catalina. I created a partition and then formatted them correctly for each version of the software.

Comment: Confirmation from terminal (text) or disk utility (picture) would be useful.